# Connect to a Bluetooth SPP device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to a device which supports Serial port profile. I'm doing so by calling:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:06:66:48:58:45");
BluetoothSocket tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
tmp.connect();
```

But doing so puts up a notification requesting to pair with the device. User intervention is acceptable, however I would prefer to have a dialog popup immediately instead of the notification. I can't seem to make this happen, but in similar apps like BlueTerm (http://pymasde.es/blueterm/) that is the behaviour.

Running on android 4.0 and 4.3

How can I ask the user directly to pair with my device, instead of showing a notification?

Comment: I think it's constructor dependant. In fact, all my BT app got a popup for pairing on Samsung S/S2/S3/S4, but on my sony xperia U, I get a notification. I think you can't do anything else :/

Comment: I get the popup on HTC One S aswell, which is running 4.1.1. But as I also said, I get the popup instead of the notification in BlueTerm, so it can't be entirely device dependant.